# Finding TensorFlow equivalent of Pytorch GRU feature

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit

I am confused about how to reconstruct the following Pytorch code in TensorFlow. It uses both the input size `x` and the hidden size `h` to create a GRU layer

```
import torch
torch.nn.GRU(64, 64*2, batch_first=True, return_state=True)
```

Instinctively, I first tried the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.layers.GRU(64, return_state=True)
```

However, I realize that it does not really account for `h` or the hidden size. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The hidden size is 64 in your tensorflow example. To get the equivalent, you should use

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.layers.GRU(64*2, return_state=True)
```

This is because the keras layer does not require you to specify your input size (64 in this example); it is decided when you build or run your model for the first time.